# data frame accessing specific rows and col from csv file in R programming

Tags: r

I have csv file contains iphone device roadmap like version number, name of model, release of model , price etc.  I have done following:

1. I have imported data set in Rstudio in variable name iphonedetail by following command. `iphonedetail <-read.csv("iphodedata.csv")`
2. Than i hv changed the attribute "name of model" to character  by using following: `iphonedetail$nameofmodel <- as.character(iphonedetail$nameofmodel)`
3. Now i need to access 1st 5 name of model and store them in vector .

I tried this to achieve  : `iphonesubset <- data.frame(iphonedetail$nameofmodel)`

Then on console i typed `iphonesubset`, but gave 0 col and row.
Could someone help in above 2 steps correct or not ? and also suggest how to fix 3rd step?

Comment: `head(iphonedetail$nameofmodel, 5)`?

Comment: what does the console give if you type `iphonedetail`? Also, shouldn't it be `"iphonedata.csv"` instead of `"iphodedata.csv"`?

Comment: Please provide example rows from your CSV file.

Comment: 1.  yes .. it is iphonedata.csv.. Here it was typo.. how do i store  1st five row in vector?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract the first five (non unique):

`iphonedf1to5 <- df[1:5,]`

That means that you get the first 5 rows and all columns. Then if you want to get the unique first five elements it should be like:

`iphonedf1to5 <- unique(df[1:5,])`

Edit:

df means your data frame of the read csv, iphonedetail in your case.